# AND operation inverse method

Tags: bitwise-operators

Lets say we have an expression:

```
A & B = C
```

Now, I am given B and C and I need to find A. How would I do it?

I am thinking this:

```
A & B = C
```

So,

```
A & B || !B = C || !B

A = C || !B
```

Would this work?

Comment: Can you make it clear if we are talking about bitwise operations or logical operations?  If it's bitwise, AND is not reversible.  Example: 111 AND 101 = 101, also 101 AND 101 = 101.  So both 111 and 101 can fit "X AND 101 = 101".

Comment: My question was on bitwise. Your example is proof it cannot be reversible. Is there a generic notation way of proving the same?

Comment: https://marc-b-reynolds.github.io/math/2017/10/13/IntegerBijections.html#fn:pscarab should help.  Also, usually just to prove something cannot be done in general, just one counterexample suffices.

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of an function, ie a function maps an input to exactly one output. For the possibility of a function to have an inverse function, every input must result in a distinct output, ie no two different input must result in the same output. Because otherwise the inverse can't be a function. That's not the case for AND, which can easily be shown, as you have four possible inputs but only two possible outputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible, because the `AND` operation does not have an inverse.

In particular, if `B` is false, `C` must also be false, but `A` could have any value.

A similar argument could be made for the `OR` operator, which also does not have an inverse. `XOR` is invertable, however.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to determine the value of A from B and C alone on every case.

We keep in mind `A && B = C`

Let's have a look at the different cases

1. If C is true, A must be true, because otherwise `A && B` can't be true.
2. If C is false and B is true, A must be false, because otherwise `A && B` can't be false.
3. If both B and C are false  A can be either true or false, you can't say because regardless of the value of A, `A && B` is always false.

So the question is, do you need an arbitrary A which fulfills the equation `A && B  = C` or do you need the "historical correct" value of A?  For the prior you can solve it unambiguously for cases 1 and 2, and choose an arbitrary value for case 3. For the latter you can also solve this for cases 1 and 2, but not for case 3.

So yes, you final equation will always give an A which fulfills the original equation. But it might not be historical correct. Ie, If originally all A, B and C are false, but your equation `C || !B` will result in the value true for A. I don't know your usecase if this is considered as correct or not.